# How to open pdf with Django ExtJs and ReportLab

Tags: django, extjs, pdf-generation, reportlab

Hi people I'm doing an Extjs application and I want to open a pdf with ReportLab when the user click on a button.

My script is:

```
xtype: 'button',
text: 'Print',
listeners: {
    click: function(evt, comp) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url : 'get_pdf',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function ( result, request ) {
                var pdf = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
                if (pdf.success) {
                    console.log('It's ok'); 
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

and server side I've a django view:

```
def get_pdf(request):

    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.pdf'

    # Create the PDF object, using the response object as its "file."
    p = canvas.Canvas(response)

    # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
    # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")

    # Close the PDF object cleanly, and we're done.
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    return response
```

When i click on the print button, Extjs give me this error: syntax error (%PDF-1.3
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you hoping Extjs is going to do with that PDF? It looks like you're trying to parse it as JSON, I can't imagine why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about about Extjs to give you a full answer, but what I can tell you is that the response text is not JSON, it's a PDF, hence the reason for the error.  What you really want to do is just display `result` in the browser, i.e. display the content of the HTTP request you initiated.  If you want to verify success, check the result's HTTP head instead.

Comment: Yes, i don't have to decode it with Ext.decode... I solved using iframe and specifying the url "get_pdf" in the "src" parameter